# Drop down menu items not visible

Tags: html, css

I have made a navigation menu bar and also two dropdown menus with 3 items each. My problem is that, below this menu, I have a slider, so when I hover my dropdown, two of the three items are hidden behind the slider.

How can I solve this?

My HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item #1</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">item #2</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">item #3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#nav {
    background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is on your z-index properties.
You need to set on #nav and #slider elements position and z-index properties.

```
#nav {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
#slider{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

That means the #nav menu will be front slider when you set a z-index property large than z-index on #slider. Have you attention that z-index doesn't work if you not set element position property like relative or absolute.

You can look this link for example - http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/